# Understanding the nodemcu-firmware repository

Tags: sockets, networking, microcontroller, esp8266, nodemcu

Just getting started with the nodemcu-firmware repository on GitHub. My goal is to implement a networking suite into the esp8266, so I will not have to do the socket programming myself. I am wondering if someone would be able to elaborate to me, what exactly is the node MCU-firmware repository used for, and if my goal would be a good fit for the repository. I am new to C programming and working with microcontrollers, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Link to nodemcu-firmware: https://github.com/jfollas/nodemcu-firmware

Comment: use the ardunio IDE if you want to program in C, nodemcu is LUA...

Comment: Do you need more feedback? If not please consider accepting the answer so that SO can [mark this as answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2):

Jason's repository is a fork of https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware. Read the intro page there, it says it all.

> NodeMCU is an eLua based firmware for the ESP8266 WiFi SOC from
>   Espressif. The firmware is based on the Espressif NON-OS SDK 1.5.4.1
>   and uses a file system based on spiffs. The code repository consists
>   of 98.1% C-code that glues the thin Lua veneer to the SDK.

The NodeMCU firmware already has a [network module](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/net/) that abstracts socket programming.